# ios facebook loginUI is blank?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing an App for IOS, using the newest facebook SDK.

The point is to allow user to post a message along with an image to their walls.

I am using FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermission to establish a connection, after that the app suppose to use FBNativeDialogs to post.
But I am not so sure why I keep getting this result:
http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/4623/screenshot2013030510421.png

The login UI suppose to ask me for permission, no? Instead it shows me nothing but a blank page.
The completionHandler of openActiveSession isn't getting called as well, indicates the loginUI doesn't return to my App.

I am fairly new to facebook integration, please help me.

I am using the following codes to establish an connection, bundle ID and app ID are already saved to facebook apps console:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                  [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                              }];

}
```

This step leads to blank login UI shown above, and the completionHandler is not getting called.

I have other steps to acquire publish permission and use native dialog to post messages, but since I can't get pass this step, I don't think its necessary to include them.

Answer (score 0):

In the Facebook tutorial openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler: is called in the appDelegate in the openSession method, and that method is fired by the login button. You are calling it from a view controller in viewDidLoad. It really should be fired by a button, not a view loading. Have you tried something like:

```
- (IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender{

SCAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate openSession];
```

with openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: implemented in the delegates openSession method? Also you may want to post more of  your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've included the code. Yes I've read the tutorial quite a few times, but I am still having this problem, maybe I missed something?

Comment: I've tried to put [openSession] in appDelegate, and fire it with a button, too, but still shows me a blank page. By the way I've tested the code on an iOS emulator without FB app installed, it's able to display the permission page in safari - http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/8250/iossimulatorscreenshot0.png - but shows "address invalid" error when I click the OK button.
My guess is it has something to do with my FB app setup, I gonna try some more tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the facebook setting, turns out I didn't even sign in, for so long I just assumed that I did, and it was causing me so much pain...